# List role users as a standard user

Tags: sql-server, database-security

Normal user can not , because of insufficient privileges , list database users that belong to a certain role.

`Execute as` does not seem to work (in a stored procedure).

Listing only returns current user.

**My question:**

How can I have a normal user (that is granted execute permission on the stored procedure in question) obtain the list of all role users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about encapsulating high-privilege functionality in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetRoleList
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT ...
END
GO
```

Of course, you should create the procedure with a user that has the rights to list role users. When the regular user executes the procedure, the owner's rights will be used instead (thus allowing to execute "elevated" queries).

Check [this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1227/granting-permission-with-the-execute-as-command-in-sql-server/) for more details.